# Why won't it call fgets?

Tags: c, string, scanf, fgets

The purpose of the code is to see how the strings are stored (whether it ends with `\n` or `\0`).

```
void print(char*);

int main(void) {

    //fscanf block
    char *ss;
    ss = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    printf("String for fscanf: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", ss);
    printf("For fscanf:\n");
    print(ss);

    //fgets block
    char *gs;
    gs = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    printf("String for fgets: ");
    fgets(gs, 10, stdin);
    printf("For fgets:\n");
    print(gs);

    free(ss);
    free(gs); 
}

void print(char* str) {
    int done = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        if (done == 3) {
            break;
        }
        if (str[i] == '\0') {
            printf("Zero: %d\n", i);
            done++;
        }
        if (str[i] == '\n') {
            printf("Return: %d\n", i);
            done++;
        }
    }
}
```

However for some reason, when I put the fscanf block first, it won't stop and req for the fgets string, it just jumps over and outputs:

```
String for fscanf: Hello
For fscanf:
Zero: 5
Zero: 6
String for fgets: For fgets:
Return: 0
Zero: 1
```

But when I put the fgets block first it works fine:

```
String for fgets: Hello
For fgets:
Return: 5
Zero: 6
String for fscanf: Hello 
For fscanf:
Zero: 5
Zero: 6
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: [Mixing scanf and fgets is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50544774/3386109)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` and `fscanf` have so many caveats [they get their own page in the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). Your particular problem of [mixing fscanf and fgets is covered by 12.18a](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html).

In short, you typed `Hello\n`. `fscanf(stdin, "%s", ss)` is reading the string `Hello`, but not the newline. That's still on `stdin`. `fgets` then reads the newline and stops. When debugging these sorts of things, it's good to put quotes around the debugging output so you can see these things. `printf("'%s'", gs);`

In general, don't mix `fscanf` and `fgets`. Stick to one or the other. Generally avoid `scanf` and `fscanf` to read and parse lines, lumping reading and parsing together causes lots of problems. Instead, use `fgets` to read the whole line and `sscanf` to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working as expected because when you do `fscanf(stdin, "%s", ss);` and when you  presses `ENTER`, it will leave `ENTER` into second buffer. Note that `ENTER` is a valid character. Hence it will read the `\n` for second input and it will not wait for `fgets(gs, 10, stdin);`. for this you need to clear the `stdin` buffer after this

```
fscanf(stdin, "%s", ss);
```

One way of getting it done is use `getchar()`. for e.g

```
//fscanf block

  getchar();/* help to clear the stdin buffer */

//fgets block
```

Also read here why one shouldn't use `scanf()` & what should be used instead of `scanf()` http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html